# Another question about the 23 day rule

Tags: death-note

Let's say there are two people with Death Notes, John Zeürtö and Bob Schnittlauchkäsebrot.

John Zeürtö writes:

> Bob Schnittlauchkäsebrot dies 23 days after the latter willingly forfeits ownership of the death note.

What would happen? Some guesses:

1. Bob dies only after 23 days after he gives up the ownership of the death note, if he does or until his lifespan runs out.
2. Bob gets killed in 23 days.
3. Bob gives up ownership of his death note and then gets killed in 23 days.
4. Bob dies of a heart attack.

Comment: Who is giving up ownership? John?

Comment: This is awfully specific. Neither, the effect will have to resolve within 23 days or it's null and void.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ It can't be void. Once a name is written in the note he will die. I assume it to be after 6mins and 40 seconds as with physically impossible deaths.

Comment: @PeterRaves Bob Schnittlauchkäsebrot is giving up the ownership

Comment: We might need a new tag: [tag:death-note-rules-puzzle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Death Note can only operate within 23 days from writing, so since the date would be impossible to fulfill it would be voided as Krazer said.

> But once the victim's name has been written, the individual's death can never be avoided. LXII

Therefore it depends on the cause of death you write down.

> In the occasion where the cause of death is possible but the situation is not, only the cause of death will take effect for that victim. If both the cause and the situation are impossible, that victim will die of heart attack. LV

By combining these rules I would expect Bob to die as soon as it is possible for him to do so according to the written cause of death.

---

http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note

Comment: so bob would die as soon he takes out his notebook?

Comment: @user6399 If John would write heart attack as the cause of death it doesn't matter what Bob does. I think he would die after 6 mins and 40 seconds of writing by John.

Comment: @user6399 Because the time of death is further in the future than 23 days, it would become void as krazer mentioned, so it would have been like John wrote *Bob dies from a heart attack*. I think.

Comment: but didn't l wrote something like: L Lawliet shall die 23 days after light yagami has died?

Comment: @PeteRaeves so if he would write another cause of death it could work?

Comment: @user6399 The cause of death isn't the issue, it's the time of death. You can't specify a time further in the future than 23 days.

Comment: but didn't l wrote something like: L Lawliet shall die 23 days after light yagami has died i know the movie has an alternate ending but still...

Comment: In the second movie L wrote "Heart attack. Dies peacefully after 23 days." http://i.stack.imgur.com/NpzXd.png

Comment: but if i wrote something like: bob schnittlauchkäsebrot bradykardie, however bradykardie will only occur when bob schnittlauchkäse without outside influence decides to give up ownership of the death note. i think this could work

Comment: @user6399 How does it matter whether or not Bob gives up his ownership? The death note can only work within 23 days. So if you write *dies 23 days after whatever* it will happen earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16591/discussion-between-user6399-and-peter-raeves).