# Is the death note 23 days rule inconsistent?

Tags: death-note

We all know about the 23 day rule. Well. I've been rewatching the series, and I've found something strange in episode 8...

At 4:10 ([youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GId34GvqXqc&t=4m10s)) Light asks Ryuk if you can use any date, as long it's before the victims lifespan, to which Ryuk replies; yes

Comment: My guess is: you can use any date, but the Death Note will kill the target 23 days after the name's been written if the date exceeds the 23 days. If instead you wrote "will die in the year 2345" even though nobody living now could live that long, then the Death Note will probably kill the target within 40 seconds, as usual (or 6 minutes and 40 seconds in case of accident). But that's just my guess.

Comment: [Related](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/12798/6166) or maybe duplicate? Although the accepted answer (mine) is only based on the rules and should probably be updated to obtain proof from the manga as Ryuk indeed says that "any time" should be possible...

Comment: Other related questions about the 23 day rule are [this](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/13551/6166) and [this](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/15364/6166)

Answer (score 2):

The 23 days rule does not apply to the time of the death but to the time of manipulation. You can manipulate someone e.g. to be a loyal sevant befor s/he dies but all manipulations can't start more than 23 day befor the death. If you give someone a task that takes more than 23 days it counts as impossible and causes a heat attack. But if you write a possible death and a date than it is perfectly fine as long as it is within the normal lief span and you are not too specific about either time or a slow cause of death.